# Dropzone.js restrict the files to one audio and one image thumbnail file.

Tags: javascript, ajax, dropzone.js

How can I restrict the files uploaded through Dropzone.js to allow user to upload only one image and one audio file . 
http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can set the max number of files with the `maxFiles` options.

The rest of your problem is slightly more complicated. You have to play with [accept](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration) and/or [events](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events).

Here's an **untested** piece of code that could help you
*(I couldn't test it on jsfiddle because the form action must point to a script that handles uploads :(  I wish I could find how they did their "upload-less" demo on the website).*

```
// "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    maxFiles: 2, // number of files
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,audio/*",
    accept: function (file, done) {
        if (new RegExp(file.type.split("/")[0]).test(this.getAcceptedFiles()[0].type)) {
            done("type already present");
        } else {
            done();
        }
    }
};
```